# Why is styling selected inputs with JavaScript not working?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to style correct selected answers green and wrong answers red (after submitting the answers). If there are only two alternatives for each question, this works fine. If there are four alternatives (like below), it only works partly. For example if you choose the last wrong answers, there will be no red styling. There are no errors. How can I make it work?

```js
let correct = document.getElementsByClassName('correct');
let wrong = document.getElementsByClassName('wrong');
let green = document.getElementsByClassName('green');
let red = document.getElementsByClassName('red');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

function checkInputs() {
  let countRightAnswers = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < correct.length; i++) {
    if (correct[i].checked) {
      green[i].style.border = '3px solid green'
      countRightAnswers++
    } else if (wrong[i].checked) {
      red[i].style.border = '3px solid red';
    }

    document.getElementById('right-answers').textContent = countRightAnswers + '/2 correct!';
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", checkInputs);
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>1. question</legend>
    <label class="green">
          <input type="radio" class="correct" name="question1">correct</label>
    <label class="red">
          <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="question1"> wrong</label>
    <label class="red">
          <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="question1"> wrong</label>
    <label class="red">
          <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="question1"> wrong</label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend class="b">2. question</legend>
    <label class="red">
          <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="question2"> wrong</label>
    <label class="red">
          <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="question2"> wrong</label>
    <label class="red">
          <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="question2"> wrong</label>
    <label class="green">
          <input type="radio" class="correct" name="question2"> correct</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<button id="btn">Answers</button>
<p id="right-answers"></p>
```

I have tried variations with for example document.querySelectorAll('input'), but it didn't work any better.

Comment: You have 2 "correct" and 6 "wrong" elements so using the same index variable `i` won't work.

Comment: your `correct` and `wrong` variables have different length but you are only iterating thru `correct` variable

Comment: FYI, if you placed the radio buttons _before_ the label elements, this could be done using CSS alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a single loop to iterate 2 different lists. For it to work, you need to go through each list individually.

I have also moved the style definitions for `green` and `red` to css classes, and am setting the class to the parent node instead of applying the style inline.

```js
let correct = document.getElementsByClassName('correct');
let wrong = document.getElementsByClassName('wrong');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

function checkInputs() {
  let countRightAnswers = 0;  

  for (i = 0; i < correct.length; i++) {
    if (correct[i].checked) {
      // set the style of the parent node
      correct[i].parentNode.classList.add('green');
      countRightAnswers++;
    }
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < wrong.length; i++) {
    if (wrong[i].checked) {
      // set the style of the parent node
      wrong[i].parentNode.classList.add('red');
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('right-answers')
    .textContent = countRightAnswers + '/2 correct!';
}

btn.addEventListener("click", checkInputs);
```

```css
.green {
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.red {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>1. question</legend>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" class="correct" name="question1">correct</label>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="question1"> wrong</label>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="question1"> wrong</label>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="question1"> wrong</label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend class="b">2. question</legend>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="question2"> wrong</label>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="question2"> wrong</label>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="question2"> wrong</label>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" class="correct" name="question2"> correct</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<button id="btn">Answers</button>
<p id="right-answers"></p>
```